# Store image and audio file in android internal storage

Tags: android

How to store image and audio files in android internal storage?

And how to retrieve back to display image in imageview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a file to your internal storage. Check this link

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

**Retrieve a File**

```
 ImageView image = new ImageView();
 Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/folder/yourfilename.png");
 image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Comment: thankq for your reply.i am asking about storing image and retrieve image and display.myself i have storing image in internals but i cant able to  display in imageview